# React-Auth-Kit Token Expiration Logout Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-hooks

I'm trying to get user Authentication working for my group project using python-flask and React TypeScript. I implemented the React-Auth-Kit library and got it pretty much working without issue so far. The problem I'm having right now is that when the token expires it logs me out (which I want to do), but in the console, I'm getting a few Errors:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`AuthProvider`) while rendering a different component (`RequireAuth`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `RequireAuth`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
   at RequireAuth (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-auth-kit.js?v=0d6edd0e:495:21)
   at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NCNQZCST.js?v=44faa96f:3115:5)
   at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NCNQZCST.js?v=44faa96f:3483:5)
   at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.tsx?t=1684444620489:38:7)
   at QueryClientProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-YI5FNOBD.js?v=44faa96f:2793:3)
   at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NCNQZCST.js?v=44faa96f:3430:15)
   at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NCNQZCST.js?v=44faa96f:3851:5)
   at AuthProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-auth-kit.js?v=0d6edd0e:445:21)
```

```
react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
    at RequireAuth (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-auth-kit.js?v=0d6edd0e:495:21)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NCNQZCST.js?v=44faa96f:3115:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NCNQZCST.js?v=44faa96f:3483:5)
    at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.tsx?t=1684444620489:38:7)
    at QueryClientProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-YI5FNOBD.js?v=44faa96f:2793:3)
    at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NCNQZCST.js?v=44faa96f:3430:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-NCNQZCST.js?v=44faa96f:3851:5)
    at AuthProvider (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-auth-kit.js?v=0d6edd0e:445:21)
```

```
Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
    at checkForNestedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:27292:11)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:25475:3)
    at dispatchReducerAction (react-dom.development.js:17452:7)
    at RequireAuth (PrivateRoute.tsx:58:15)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:20)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:5)
```

main.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import Favicon from "react-favicon";
import favIcon from "./assets/Efavicon.ico";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "@tanstack/react-query-devtools";

import { AuthProvider } from "react-auth-kit";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const queryClient = new QueryClient({});

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider
      authType={"cookie"}
      authName={"_auth"}
      cookieDomain={window.location.hostname}
      cookieSecure={false}
    >
      <BrowserRouter>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <Favicon url={favIcon} />
          <App />
          <ReactQueryDevtools />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.tsx:

```
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./Pages/login";
import Footer from "./Components/Footer/Footer";
import CreateAccount from "./Pages/CreateAccount";
import ForgotPassword from "./Pages/ForgotPassword";
import RecMain from "./Pages/RecMain";
import Watchlist from "./Pages/Watchlist";
import Title from "./Components/Title/Title";
import Testing from "./Components/Testing/Testing";
import SearchPage from "./Pages/SearchPage";
import useToken from "./Services/useToken";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar/Navbar";
import { RequireAuth } from "react-auth-kit";

function App() {
  const { token, removeToken, setToken, setUserID, userID } = useToken(); //old code to be removed
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar token={token} setToken={setToken} userId={userID} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/create-account" element={<CreateAccount />} />
        <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />

        {/* main page */}
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />

        <Route
          path="/main"
          element={
            <RequireAuth loginPath="/">
              <RecMain />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/watchlist"
          element={
            <RequireAuth loginPath="/">
              <Watchlist />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/title/:id"
          element={
            <RequireAuth loginPath="/">
              <Title />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/searching"
          element={
            <RequireAuth loginPath="/">
              <SearchPage />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        ></Route>
        <Route
          path="/testing"
          element={
            <RequireAuth loginPath="/">
              <Testing />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        ></Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

login.tsx:

```
import axios from "axios";
import LoginForm from "../Components/Forms/LoginForm";
import styles from "../Components/Forms/formBox.module.css";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSignIn } from "react-auth-kit";

interface LoginProps {
  setToken: (token: string) => void;
  setUserID: (userID: string) => void;
}

function Login() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const signIn = useSignIn();

  return (
    <div className={styles.login}>
      <LoginForm
        onSubmit={(user) =>
          axios
            .post("http://localhost:5000/token", {
              email: user.email,
              password: user.password,
            })
            .then((response) => {
              signIn({
                token: response.data.access_token,
                expiresIn: 5, //time for token expiration
                tokenType: "Bearer",
                authState: { userId: response.data.user_id },
              });
              navigate("/main");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              if (error.response) {
                console.log(error.response);
                console.log(error.response.status);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
              }
            })
        }
      ></LoginForm>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

I am new to React so I'm not sure if this is something to do with the backend or frontend? (backend shows no errors) Please let me know if any other information would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed downgrading my react and react-dom (and the @types/react and @types/react-dom if you are using Typescript) versions from 18.2.0 to 17.0.2.

Check this issue: https://github.com/react-auth-kit/react-auth-kit/issues/1243